# Hive - ELSE in SUM

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

The following runs fine on as  SQL on an RDBMS database. However, this fails to run on hive.

```
SELECT
        entry_date,
        customer,
        cust_loc,
        SUM(run_time) AS TOTAL_RUN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 THEN entry_date ELSE 0 END) AS SLOT_1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 200001 AND 30000 THEN entry_date ELSE 0 END) AS SLOT_2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 31000 AND 40000 THEN entry_date ELSE 0 END) AS SLOT_3
FROM
        cust_run_details
WHERE
        app_env IN ('a','b')
        AND entry_date = '2015-02-01'
        AND flag_set='U'
GROUP BY
        customer,
        customer,
        cust_loc
```

The error I get when I run on HIVE is

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10016]: Line 6:80 Argument type mismatch '0': The expression after ELSE should have the same type as those after THEN: "string" is expected but "int" is found
```

How can I convert this to Hive equivalent? Please any ideas would help me here

Comment: Changed the SUM to COUNT & got rid of "ELSE 0". Took a long time to get there. Sigh..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `entry_date` is a `date`, you probably do not want to `sum()` it.  If you want the sum of the run times in the different ranges, then you want a `select` like this:

```
 SELECT entry_date,
        customer,
        cust_loc,
        SUM(run_time) AS TOTAL_RUN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 THEN run_time ELSE 0 END) AS SLOT_1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 200001 AND 30000 THEN run_time ELSE 0 END) AS SLOT_2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 31000 AND 40000 THEN run_time ELSE 0 END) AS SLOT_3
```

If you want a count of the run times in the different ranges, then:

```
 SELECT entry_date,
        customer,
        cust_loc,
        SUM(run_time) AS TOTAL_RUN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SLOT_1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 200001 AND 30000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SLOT_2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 31000 AND 40000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SLOT_3
```

If `entry_date` could be `NULL` and you want to ignore those records, then you can include `and entry_date is not null` in the `WHEN` condition.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the SUM to COUNT & got rid of "ELSE 0". Took a long time to get there. Sigh..

```
SELECT
        entry_date,
        customer,
        cust_loc,
        SUM(run_time) AS TOTAL_RUN,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 THEN entry_date END) AS SLOT_1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 200001 AND 30000 THEN entry_date END) AS SLOT_2,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN run_time BETWEEN 31000 AND 40000 THEN entry_date END) AS SLOT_3
FROM
        cust_run_details
WHERE
        app_env IN ('a','b')
        AND entry_date = '2015-02-01'
        AND flag_set='U'
GROUP BY
        customer,
        customer,
        cust_loc
```